# Typescript definitions file cannot make a method implement an object interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to generate a definition file for pnotify.

```
/// <reference path="./jquery.d.ts"/>

interface pnotifyDefaults {
    styling?: string;
    history?: boolean;
}

interface pnotifyInterface {
    defaults?: pnotifyDefaults
}

interface JQueryStatic {
    pnotify(options: any): any;

    pnotify: pnotifyInterface;

    pnotify_remove_all(): void;

}


declare module 'jquery.pnotify' {
}
```

This accutally does not compile and the compiler complains:

```
Duplicate identifier 'pnotify'. Additional locations: jquery.pnotify.d.ts(15,5)
```

But how can I achieve that behaviour as in my js code I want to use pnotify like:

```
$.pnotify(opts)
```

But also like that:

```
$.pnotify.defaults.history = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a call signature on `pnotifyInterface`, update your definitions to:

```
interface pnotifyDefaults {
    styling?: string;
    history?: boolean;
}

interface pnotifyInterface {
    defaults?: pnotifyDefaults
    (options: any): any;
}

interface JQueryStatic {
    pnotify: pnotifyInterface;

    pnotify_remove_all(): void;

}


declare module 'jquery.pnotify' {
}
```

You were receiving the error because you were declaring `pnotify` twice on the `JQueryStatic` interface.